# Gradle generating incorrect POM subproject info

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an `Android` project using `Gradle 2.2`, it has 2 sub projects and one is dependent on the other. I am using `Maven plugin` to deploy to `Artifactory` and it isn't generating the correct POM.

```
-project
 -subproject1 
 -subproject2 (depends on subproject1)
```

subproject1/build.gradle, generates a JAR:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

def version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
def artifactId = 'subproject1'
def groupId    = 'com.xxx.yyy'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
    compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'https://my-artifactory-repo' ) {
                authentication(userName: ..., password: ...)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'https://my-artifactory-repo' ) {
                authentication(userName: ..., password: ...)
            }
            pom.version = version
            pom.artifactId = artifactId
            pom.groupId = groupId
        }
    }
}

task installArchives(type: Upload) {
    configuration = configurations['archives']
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository url: 'my-local-repo-path'
            pom.version    = version
            pom.artifactId = artifactId
            pom.groupId    = groupId
        }
    }
}
```

The subproject1 POM is generated correctly.

subproject2/build.gradle, generates an AAR:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile project(':subproject1')
}
```

The subproject2 POM is not generated correctly, for `subproject1`, the `groupid` has the same value as artifactId and `version` is unspecified. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you set `group` and `version` for both subprojects?

Comment: Yes I did, I forgot to mention that one is a JAR and the other an AAR which has the incorrect POM for the dependent JAR file.

Comment: Please show any configuration of `group`, `version`, or `jar` and all publishing related configuration in subproject1/build.gradle

Comment: Try setting `(project.)group` and `(project.)version`. Shouldn't be necessary to explicitly set `pom.groupId`, `pom.artifactId`, and `pom.version`.

Comment: So replace `pom.version` with (project.)version`, etc? Should I do that for `subproject2` also? I also have a top level `build.gradle` file, making sure I am putting it in the right place. `

Comment: These properties need to be set at the outermost level of the build script. Typically, `group` and `version` are the same for all projects, and hence set in `allprojects { ... }` of the root build script.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, if you want to add this as your answer, I am happy to mark it. Should setting `pom.version` and `pom.groupId` have worked? I left `pom.artifactId` as is. Also, I might need to specify a different version for each of the subproject. If there is a place where this is documented, please let know.

Comment: `pom.version` and `pom.groupId` are just about the generated POM, and don't affect anything else. They default to `project.version` and `project.group`, respectively, and there should rarely be a need to set them explicitly. Not sure which documentation you are looking for, but many if not all Gradle samples for multi-project builds and publishing set `project.group` and `project.version` rather than `pom.version` and `pom.groupId`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to separate out the version for the subprojects since I need to be able to change each one.